# Moving files to corresponding folder

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm using C# language for finding certain files and moving them to corresponding folder. I'm using this code bellow, but files that I'm getting lately cannot be read with this code. Before name of the file would be for example "File_20141120", but files that I'm getting now are named, for example: ABC (222), ACD (2), DES (33), so I need to write a code that will read numbers in parentheses and move it to folder with the same number. 
The code I'm using right now:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string filename;
        string datepart;
        bool FolderExistFlg;
        filename = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
        datepart = (filename.Substring(filename.Length - 12)).Substring(0, 8);
        FolderExistFlg = Directory.Exists(Dts.Variables["OutputMainFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + datepart);

        if (!FolderExistFlg)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Dts.Variables["OutputMainFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + datepart);
        }

        File.Move(Dts.Variables["SourceFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + filename,
        Dts.Variables["OutputMainFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + datepart + "\\" + filename);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using C# to move files in SSIS ? There is a File Task that can move, copy, delete, rename for both files and folders.

Comment: I have more than 1000 files and File Task is not a good option for that because it does not match file name with folder name. File task is good for smaller set of date  as I understood. I'm still learning SSIS, but I tried to use File Task and it did not give me results I wanted.

Comment: do you have a example for the filename including the extension?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to extract the folder name from between the two parens `()`. If that's the case, a simple RegEx will work for you:

```
// Extracts only the number between the parens
// E.g. Filename: aaa (333)
// Output: 333
var folderNumber = Regex.Match(
                        filename,
                        @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: This would work if I have only one destination folder for all files, but the problem is that I have one folder with many destination folders in it. So I need a code that will find that destination folder and move my file to corresponding folder with the same #. For example if I have a file "aaaa (333)" it needs to go to folder named "(333)".

Comment: @S.Vojnovic, I'm not sure I understand the problem. The code above takes a file with the name `aaaa (333)` and extracts the folder name, `333`. You can then use that information to save it to the appropriate folder. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is optimized for the task you are performing. If we assume that all files in the source folder need to be moved, then place the file task in a for each loop and parameterize the source and destination variables.

Create five variables:

1. SourceFolder
2. DestinationFolder
3. FileName
4. SourceFileNameWithPath       = SourceFolder + "\" + FileName
5. DestinationFileNameWithPath  = DestinationFolder + "\" + FileName

Use the ForEach loop to loop over the SourceFolder and read in each file name (select File Name and Extension) into the FileName variable (note: set FileSpec to either *.* or *.) . In the File Task, set the source variable to SourceFileNameWithPath and the destination variable to DestinationFileNameWithPath.

The File System Task should be Rename File.

https://www.tutorialgateway.org/move-multiple-files-using-file-system-task-in-ssis/